# Selenium - NoSuchElementException after switching from frame[0] to window[1] - Firefox GeckoDriver Error - Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

I have receive an error, `element not found` in the Firefox GeckoDriver browser

when i switch from window[1] to frame[0], back to window[1], and then click the close frame button.

I want to continue using `GeckoDriver` because i was having performance issues with `ChromeDriver`. Sorry this is an internal website and I can't share the `HTML`.

1. I have done the following to pinpoint the issue.

   - Tested with exact same code and works properly in Chrome driver
   - Works in Firefox when i switch to window[1] click the `openframe` button, and then click the `closeframe` button, without switching to frame[0].
   - I can switch to frame[0], switch back to window[1] and do a `driver.close()` and it will close window[1].
   - I can read the `driver.page_source` from window[1] after switching back from frame[0] and see that the element is still in the `page_source` and has not changed.
   - I can switch from frame[0] back to window[0] and click the button to re-open window[1] and that works properly. Then i can click the open and close frame buttons.

So the problem just resides on switching from frame[0] back to window[1], then trying to click an element in window[1] in Firefox GeckoDriver.

Python: 2.7
Selenium: 3.0.1
GeckoDriver:  v0.13.0
Firefox: 51.0.1

Here is the code:

```
firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
driver.get('www.internalwebsite.com')
driver.find_element_by_id('opensnewwindow').click()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_id('opennewframe').click()
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
//read contents
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_id('closeframe').click()
```

Error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="closeframe"]

Comment: You're using indexes for the switching, are you sure your indexes are correct after opening / closing the frames? Try switching by frame names and mainWindow.

Answer (score 0):

The code below seemed to do the trick. Still not sure why though.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()

firefox_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
firefox_capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=firefox_capabilities)
driver.get('www.internalwebsite.com')
driver.find_element_by_id('opensnewwindow').click()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_id('opennewframe').click()
driver.switch_to_frame(0)
//read contents
driver.switch_to.default_content()
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_id('closeframe').click()
```