# Not able to automate entering login credentials in Username and Password input fields

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am writing scripts for automating login action with credentials . I followed the standard process of finding the element through name , class , xpath . The input fields are not taking the credentials . I tried giving time interval of 10 seconds  in between each process , still the issue continues.

Below I have attested the code .

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import  By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get()   #WEBSITE HERE

time.sleep(10)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ssousernameUI"]')

elem.clear()
elem.send_keys()  # USERNAME HERE

elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)

passwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')

passwd.clear()

passwd.send_keys()  #PASSWORD HERE

passwd.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(10)

login = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Login")

login.click()
```

ERROR MESSAGE :

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/think201/PycharmProjects/pat/pat-cbt/login.py", line 13, 
  in <module>
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ssousernameUI"]')


  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 368, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)



  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 858, in find_element
'value': value})['value']



  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)




  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response



raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to 
locate element: //*[@id="ssousernameUI"]
```

HTML code

```html
          
         <form name="loginForm" action="https://login.asdfghjk.in/oam/server/auth_cred_submit" target="_top" id="loginForm" method="POST">   
   
<!-- Taksh End -->

<input name="ipRandomValue" value="709381701517861" id="ipRandomValue" type="hidden"><input name="deviceTypeHidden" value="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0" id="deviceTypeHidden" type="hidden">
<input name="ssousername" value="" id="ssousername" type="hidden">
<input name="hashnumber" value="" id="hashnumber" type="hidden"> 


<!-- Start mainWrapper -->
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div style="top: 20%;left: 50%;position: fixed;z-index: 5;color: white;display:none;" class="wait">
    <h1>Please wait...</h1>
</div>

<div class="overlay1"></div>
<div class="mainWrapper"> 
  <!-- Start Header -->
  
  
  <!-- End Header --> 
  
  <!-- Start Middle Container -->
  <article class="midContainer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="breadcrums">
        <p>You are here:</p>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:;">Home</a></li>
          <li class="last"> Login</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <h1> Login</h1>
      <section class="RHSsection standardWide">
        <div class="pageWrap">
          <div class="loginWrp">
            <div class="box vfAcc">
            
            <!-- displaying error message -->
            <div class="cl c414042 bold fnt16"><p style="color:red;margin-left:10px;"><br><strong class="errMsgClass"></strong></p></div>
            <div class="cl c414042 bold fnt16" id="SrvError"></div>
            <div style="display:none;" class="cl c414042 bold fnt16 lockClass"><p style="color:red;margin-left:10px;"><br><strong>Your account is locked since it is 
not used for a long time. Please <a href="https://qwertyu.in/CSSPortal/faces/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/pages/forgotPassword.jspx">click here </a> to activate it</strong></p></div>
               
            <!-- displaying error message end -->
              
              <h3 class="accor">Login to manage your Account <span class="drop"></span></h3>
              <div class="setWrp">
                <div class="row">
                  <label>Enter your username or mobile number</label>
                  <div class="inputArea">
                    <div class="inputFieldBox">
                    
                    
                     <input name="ssousernameUI" autocomplete="off" class="login_input width255" value="" onfocus="if
(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" id="ssousernameUI" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" type="text">
                          <div class="error_msg"></div>                  
                    </div>
                 </div> 
                  
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <label>Enter your password</label>
                  <div class="inputArea">
                    <div class="inputFieldBox">
                      
                      <input name="password" autocomplete="off" id="password" class="login_input width255" onkeydown="if ((event.keyCode == 
13) &amp;&amp; (document.getElementById('ssousernameUI').value!='') &amp;&amp; (document.getElementById('passwordsrv').value!='')){LoginValidation();}" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" value="" onfocus="if
(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" type="password">
                         <div class="error_msg"></div>                    
                    </div> 
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="checkboxBtn"> <span class="uncheked"></span>
                    <input name="checkbox" id="RememberMe" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="RememberMe"> Remember Me </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="forgot"> <a href="https://qwertyuio.in/CSSPortal/faces/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/pages/forgotPassword.jspx" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Forgot Password'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Forgot Password' });">Forgot your password?</a></div>
                </div>
                
                <a href="javascript:;" onclick="ajaxLoginValidation();" class="purpleBtn">Login</a><!-- Add Here : Taksh -->
                
                
              <!--  <div class="col orline"><span class="or">Or</span></div>
                <ul class="smoShare">
                  <li class="facebook"><a href="javascript:;">Facebook</a></li>
                  <li class="gplus"><a href="javascript:;">Google Plus</a></li>
                </ul> -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box myvf">
              <h3 class="accor">Why should I register ? <span class="drop"></span></h3>
              <div class="setWrp">
                <p>Here are 5 great reasons! </p>
                <ul class="redbult">
                  <li>Simplified, dashboard view of voice &amp; Internet usage</li>
                  <li> Easy update of profile &amp; contact info</li>
                  <li> Quick change of voice &amp; plans</li>
                  <li> Hassle-free access to old bills &amp; statements of accounts</li>
                  <li> Instant activation/deactivation of services</li>
                </ul>
                <p>It takes just a few moments!</p>
                <a href="https://qwertyuio.in/CSSPortal/faces/oracle/webcenter/portalapp/pages/Registration.jspx" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Register Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Register Now', Internal_Journey : 'MyAccount Login: My VF Registration'});" class="purpleBtn">Register Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="box vfApp">
              <h3 class=""> App</h3>
              <div class="">
                <div class="vfappSlide">
                  <div class="owl-vfapp owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
                    
                    
                <!--    <div class="apps"> <img src="/images/appimages/windows_logo.jpg"  alt="" />
                      <p>Manage your account on the go !</p>
                        <div class="getNow"><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Windows - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: windows App - Get Now' });" href="http://qwertyu" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="apps"> <img src="/images/appimages/blackberry_logo.png"  alt="" />
                      <p>Manage your Vodafone account on the go !</p>
                      <div class="getNow"><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Blackberry - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Blackberry App - Get Now' });" href="http://qwerty" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="apps"> <img src="/images/appimages/nokia_ovi_logo.jpg"  alt="" />
                      <p>Manage your account on the go !</p>
                       <div class="getNow"><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'OVI - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Ovi App - Get Now' });" href="http://qwertyu" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>                      
                       </div>
                      <div class="apps"> <img src="/images/appimages/java_logo.jpg"  alt="" />
                      <p>Manage your account on the go !</p>
                       <div class="getNow"><a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Java - Get Now');utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Java App - Get Now' });" href="http://qwertyui" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                       </div> -->
                  <div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(-837px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 1674px;"><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 279px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="apps"> <img alt="" src="/images/appimages/android_logo1.jpg">
                      <p>Manage your Vodafone account on the go !</p>
                        <div class="getNow"><a href="http://asdfgh" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Android - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Android App - Get Now' });" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                        </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 279px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="apps"> <img alt="" src="/images/appimages/apple_logo1.jpg">
                      <p>Manage your Vodafone account on the go !</p>
                       <div class="getNow"><a href="http://qwertyu" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Apple - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: iphone App - Get Now' });" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                     
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item" style="width: 279px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="apps"> <img alt="" src="/images/appimages/android_logo1.jpg">
                      <p>Manage your Vodafone account on the go !</p>
                        <div class="getNow"><a href="http://asdfghj" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Android - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Android App - Get Now' });" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                        </div></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 279px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="apps"> <img alt="" src="/images/appimages/apple_logo1.jpg">
                      <p>Manage your  account on the go !</p>
                       <div class="getNow"><a href="http://asdfghjk" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Apple - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: iphone App - Get Now' });" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                     
                    </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 279px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="apps"> <img alt="" src="/images/appimages/android_logo1.jpg">
                      <p>Manage your  account on the go !</p>
                        <div class="getNow"><a href="http://asdfghjk" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Android - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: Android App - Get Now' });" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                        </div></div><div class="owl-item cloned" style="width: 279px; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="apps"> <img alt="" src="/images/appimages/apple_logo1.jpg">
                      <p>Manage your  account on the go !</p>
                       <div class="getNow"><a href="" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'My Account', 'Click', 'Apple - Get Now'); utag.link({ Custom_Links : 'MyAccount: Login: iphone App - Get Now' });" class="purpleBtn">Get Now</a> </div>
                     
                    </div></div></div></div><div class="owl-controls"><div class="owl-nav"><div class="owl-prev" style="display: none;">prev</div><div class="owl-next" style="display: none;">next</div></div><div style="" class="owl-dots"><div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div><div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div></div></div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  
  <!-- End Middle Container --> 
  
</div>
<!-- End mainWrapper -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You . I resolved it .

The website had multiple login pages , hence they have used iframe to suffice the Login access in multiple pages.

The issue was , the login was inside a iframe . I referred to the documentation for switching through frame.
I used

```
        driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

Thank you @Arun Prakash and everyone.

Comment: Accept answers if it helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

NoSuchElementException is because webdriver is not able to find the element in the webpage. Check if there are any frames in the webpage. Switch to it, if any.

Comment: Yes , If I open  SHOW ONLY THIS FRAME  by clicking on the username field , it's taking the credentials . How do I access only this frame ?     If I view the frame source , it's written in javascript .

Comment: Can you post the relevant html/js for the iframe?

Comment: @Josh There's no element iframe .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to click the element to get that element to focus and then enter username/password details.
If that also does not work try wrapping your find element statement with explicit wait.
Let me know if that helps.

EDIT1:

```
elem.click();
elem.send_keys();
time.sleep(50);
```

EDIT2:
Instead of:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ssousernameUI"]')
```

you can try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ssousernameUI"]').click()
```

Comment: No Mayur , It doesn't .

Comment: Please refer to EDIT2 of my answer and let me know.

Comment: Mayur , I tried that too . I guess the issue is with the frame in the webpage as @Arun mentioned . But I am not able to find the frame element in the HTML code .

Comment: @Karthikziffer, try the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42033485/selenium-nosuchelementexception-after-switching-from-frame0-to-window1-f)

Answer (score 0):

For the first look, it seems that you xpath is not a correct one.
Instead of using:

> elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ssousernameUI"]')

Try this:

> elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ssousernameUI']")

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared to fill up the `credentials` you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your_website")   #WEBSITE HERE
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ssousernameUI']").click()
username.clear()
username.send_keys("user_name")  # USERNAME HERE
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='password']").click()
password.clear()
password.send_keys("Pa$$w0rd")  #PASSWORD HERE
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='purpleBtn' and contains(.,'Login')]").click()
```